# GPS application targeting mobile devices

Tags: web-applications, android, ios, app

I'm working on making a product for tracking workers/staffs locations and in that case the application need to be able to run on the phone for at least 10 hours without the phone suddenly closing the app.
I cannot find too much information on how I can make sure the app are not being closed and how the app can run in the background and still receive location change events.

The code is based on xamarin. 
So the question is, would there be any difference in app priority in these cases:

1. Running the app as an wasm app from the browser on the phone
2. Creating an "shell app" with a WebView and then running the wasm app from there
3. Creating a xamarin app

The app should target IOS and Android

The app will do all the calculation on the phone and not send any location data back to the server. It will just report "now and then" "2 hours at customer x, 1 hour at customer y"

What would be the best way to make sure the app will run the whole day after it has been opened?

Comment: Great with negative feedback, but it would be even greater with some information on why this question is bad

Answer (score 0):

The ten hours is a bit pushing it.

On iOS you would likely us an “Enterprise account” instead of the usual developer account. The app can only be used within your company, but doesn’t have privacy restrictions.

Otherwise, you’ll have to ask the user to agree to location tracking at all times. The app can not enforce this (and will not be allowed on the App Store if it doesn’t work without this).

Comment: This is not for inhouse use. The user has to agree on using their location if they want to use the app.